# Hacking SVG Fonts

Tags: svg, inkscape

I know nothing about SVG. Even less about SVG fonts. However, I need to use them in my web project.

I've created a custom font with fontello and analyzed the format of the SVG file in a text editor. Then I opened an SVG file created with Inkscape (saved as plain SVG) and used its `d` attribute to create a new glyph in the font.

I couldn't believe that it actually worked ... well, almost ... the glyph appears flipped vertically. I have tried flipping it in Inskcape. However, when I save the file, the original `d` attribute is left as it was. It just adds a `transform` with a matrix that flips the coordinate system, but which does now work in the `<glyph>` tag.

Is there any way I could apply this transformation in the font file, or in Inkscape, to change the `d` attibute?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this blogpost will help you a bit: http://www.heydonworks.com/article/font-hacking

Comment: @ErikDahlström: Thanks! I wish I had found it before I started experimenting ... It would have saved me a few hours of trial and error. But it was fun :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, in Inkscape, ungrouping and then grouping the object applies the transformation to the coordinates.